# Only black and white wires, no bare ground coming from ceiling

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, led, recessed-lighting

I'm quite new to home electrical work. I have 6 thin LED pot lights I would like to set up in my dining room. Each one has a box, expecting hot, neutral and bare ground wires:

[image: LED pot light box]

I removed the old light that was there, and a black and white wire was the result. No bare copper ground wire. I taped and capped the wires to be safe. It would appear that the light switch only controls whatever is connected to these wires:

[image: black and white wire]

What should I do about the missing bare copper ground wire? Could it be up there somewhere? Should I look for it? Or should I removed everything coming from the light switch and start with a fresh piece of 14/2 Romex?

Another question, what is this above my faux tile? Is it a layer of insulation? Should the LED boxes be installed above this?

[image]

Comment: If your wires are in a metal box, it could be your "missing" ground. If so, connect the fixture's green wire to the box using an approved screw.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking squarely into the hole in the ceiling the wires are exiting from?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Tried to get a pic but there really isn't anything to see, there is a layer of insulation (at least I think that's what it is) out of which the wires protrude right above and pressing against the faux tile, not really any space into which I can look.

Comment: What's in the light switch box?

Comment: it looks like you have a blue wire that is grounded to the box

Comment: @Ruskes Really? How can you tell?